# Bluetooth discovery and signal strength (RSSI)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth

I need some kind of code sample to make a bluetooth "radar" in Visual Studio Community 2015 with Visual C#. I just need to detect the nearby Bluetooth devices and the transmission signal.

I only get here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff536587(v=vs.85).aspx

Found some old library (32FEET) but outdated.

But not even a single C# example. I need Bluetooth LE but i don't mind just test bluetooth 2.0.

In Java i found *bluecode* and in Linux **bluez** libraries.

Edit: for Windows 7

Comment: Do you want to detect iBeacons or all kind of BLE devices?

Comment: Also add what version of Windows you want to support, because as from Windows 8.1, there is API for BLE. As of Windows 10, there is API for detecting Beacon advertisement data...

Comment: I don't need BLE right now. I think BLE is only from Windows 8.1. I edited the first message: i need the code for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is too broad but I'll answer it anyway.

Since your target is Windows 7, you won't get BLE support out of the box (as it is first introduced in Windows 8.1). You could work around this by talking to the dongle directly (like I do in the open source [WinBeacon](https://github.com/huysentruitw/win-beacon) library) or by using a VM/Raspberry PI that runs Linux with bluez-stack that exposes some kind of Web API you can use.

For detecting BT 2.0 devices, I would recommend the [32feet](https://32feet.codeplex.com/) library as I've used it in the past for detecting and pairing and it just works. When using the Microsoft BT stack, the 32feet library uses the Windows Bluetooth Socket API, which is well documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So if you only want to scan for devices, you might as well directly use the Socket API and use the 32feet source code as inspiration.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. But i still can't get a simple example for reading the bluetooth devices in Visual Studio 2015/Windows7/+usb bluetooth dongle. In Ubuntu i just installed bluez and with a simple C program i get the bluetooth device list and signal strenght. I just want a sample project for Visual Studio Community 2015 to list the bluetooth devices in C#. I can only find C++ examples.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to do some effort yourself. It is really not that hard and will be great for learning how to use (API) documentation.

Comment: I am used to PHP.net documentation with small examples, the microsoft API is not informative for me. I will kepp trying hard, thank you. Meanwhile i will develop the IOS and Android versions. The IOS doc is amazingly informative (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html) and the Android Studio too: (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) even with step by step issues.  Thanks again!