# Bluetooth scan C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth, windows-10, rssi

I'm developing a C# WinForms app on Windows 10. I want to perform a Bluetooth environment scan and get devices list all around the PC. I also want the RSSI of each device.

I have tried 32feet library but I can't access RSSI.

Have you a solution or should I migrate to WPF/UWP?

Comment: Look into this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807308/bluetooth-discovery-and-signal-strength-rssi

Comment: I assume you've seen the [RSSI section](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Peer-Device-Information#rssi) under the 32feet docs for Peer Device Information. What you're asking for may be impossible on Windows desktop.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Thanks, RSSI access is impossible with windows 7 or under. But it is possible to access it with Windows 10 (the platform i'm using).
I have tried 32feet on windows 10 and RSSI doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is 32f lib witch is not compatible.

Comment: It may be helpful to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46729280/edit) to include more details about what you mean by "doesn't seem to work". Can you not find the a function/property that gets you the info? Is the information returned not what you expect? Do you get an error? The code you are currently using to access RSSI would also be useful to add in an edit to the original question.

Comment: @khmub This topic is for Windows 7 and there are many differences between 7 and 10 for bluetooth

Comment: @JeffBridgman with 32feet on win10 when I access to the RSSI value I have already the same for differents devices and it's not a correct value.
eg: it should be: -80dBm and i have : 22564.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, I have found a solution [here](https://blog.cinlogic.com/2017/02/01/getting-started-with-ibeacons-and-windows-10/).

1. You first have to install Windows10 development kit.
2. Then in your project you have to add this library:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
   ```

   Or you can install the "UwpDesktop" NuGet Package.
3. This works with Console app, Winforms, WPF and UWP.
4. Here is a simple example:

   ```
   using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

   namespace BeaconExample
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
               watcher.Received += Watcher_Received;
               watcher.Start();
           }

           private static void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(args.BluetoothAddress.ToString("x") + ";" + args.RawSignalStrengthInDBm);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Link-only answers can be problematic (since the link could get broken later). It'd be helpful to the community if you summarized what the solution was. For example, maybe you had to pick a different project type or platform... or use a particular nuget package... or maybe the property wasn't called what you expected.... all useful information to the next person with this question :)