# Get Bluetooth Devices sorted by strength/proximity

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

I am trying to build a solution in C# which allows the identification of a laptop based on the Bluetooth devices around it. I hope to preferably use Bluetooth LE and have the ability to know which devices are more likely relevant by their strength.

My first idea was to use RSSI, but it seems that path is near impossible due to how Microsoft's Bluetooth Stack doesn't support reading the RSSI values. I've even looked into using Nobel with edge.js, however, that requires you to replace your Bluetooth driver entirely (making it useless for anything else) in order to support RSSI readings which is currently my last resort, as it would make it difficult for users to adopt.

However, I only really need which devices are more relevant/closer.

Is there any way I could get the Bluetooth devices in range ordered from closest to furthest in C#? Or maybe even in JS?

Thank you.

Comment: If RSSI path with default Microsoft stack seems impossible. Try to download a BLE scanner application and make it log the scanned contents along with RSSI value in a *.txt file. Read that file from your code and try filtering RSSI values from it. A similar approach was followed by us in Android using LightBlue app. I am searching a similar app for windows if I get any will comment here.

Comment: @NitinJadhav Hopefully an application out there exists. I'll try looking into it as well.

Comment: I found Bennett but even they seem to have struggled showing the signal strength on their application. It sucks Microsoft couldn't provide at least something to access the Rssi of bluetooth devices

Comment: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46729280/9908376